# Zombinet: "Error: Invalid credential file path: config"

Tags: zombienet

When trying to run a zombienet test locally, I get the error:

> Error: Invalid credential file path: config

The test is copied from the Polkadot-SDK Repo:

**0001-parachains-smoke-test.toml**

```
[settings]
timeout = 1000

[relaychain]
default_image = "{{ZOMBIENET_INTEGRATION_TEST_IMAGE}}"
chain = "rococo-local"
command = "polkadot"

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "alice"
  args = [ "--alice", "-lruntime=debug,parachain=trace" ]

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "bob"
  args = [ "--bob", "-lruntime=debug,parachain=trace" ]

[[parachains]]
id = 100
addToGenesis = false

  [parachains.collator]
  name = "collator01"
  image = "{{COL_IMAGE}}"
  command = "adder-collator"
  args = [ "-lruntime=debug,parachain=trace" ]

[types.Header]
number = "u64"
parent_hash = "Hash"
post_state = "Hash"
```

**0001-parachains-smoke-test.zndsl**

```
Description: Smoke Test
Network: ./0001-parachains-smoke-test.toml
Creds: config

alice: parachain 100 is registered within 225 seconds
alice: parachain 100 block height is at least 10 within 400 seconds
```

The command I am running is:

```
./zombienet-macos test zombienet-config/tests/0001-parachains-smoke-test.zndsl
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Zombienet documentation:

> Creds: ............ Credentials file name or path to use (Only with kubernetes provider), we look in the current directory or in $HOME/.kube/ if a filename is passed.

Based on your command, it seems you are trying to run the tests locally, and thus you should use the native provider, by passing the `--provider native` flag to zombienet.

So the final command you should run is:

```
./zombienet-macos test --provider=native zombienet-config/tests/0001-parachains-smoke-test.zndsl
```

Comment: That correct, by `default` zombienet will try to run your test using the `k8s` provider. Also, worth mention that zombienet will try to replace those` {{SOME_VALUE}}` in the network definition file (`toml`) with looking at your env variables.